# How could a large open source project manage the Pull Requests?

Tags: github, pull-request

I was thinking about a very complicated GitHub open source project, how to manage pull requests. For example, [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pulls?page=39&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen) there are close to a thousand pull requests .

How could the k8s administrator validate the correctness of those pull requests?  How could they efficiently verify and merge them to master?  In short, I want to know how the k8s administrator can manage such a complex project, and if there is more than one, how they divide the work to control so many pull requests.

Comment: What makes you believe there is a single "k8s administrator"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Large bazaar-style open source projects usually don't just have one but many maintainers who review pull requests. Those often specialize in specific sub-modules of the application, so they have a better view of what is and isn't an appropriate contribution for that particular module.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways to validate pull requests:

1. Some projects expect there to be an accepted issue before a PR is submitted.  So, you can check the PR easily to see if it connects to an existing issue and then see if that issue is one that the team has said can move forward.
2. Hopefully on any large project there are a slew of tests integrated into some CI/CD system.  Automation may even be setup so that a merge is blocked if these tests are failing.
3. Delegation, as [Philipp mentioned](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/12173/990).